# Removing file pattern with git-update-index --remove

Tags: git

How to provide file pattern rather a particular file in **`git-update-index --remove`** command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like

```
git update-index --remove -- $(git ls-files '*.c')
```

Comment: Be sure to quote your wildcard in the ls-files clause so it's not interpreted by the shell.

Comment: gah, I should have known better :|

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. But when I am using it inside a filter branch statement with the pattern in a local variable "pattern" its not working, 
pattern='*.c'
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --verbose --remove -- "$(git ls-files -- $"(pattern)")"' HEAD

Comment: $"(pattern)" tries to expand a variable called "(pattern)" which isn't what you want.

The additional quotes around the $(git ls-files...) invocation are probably wrong too--- they'll convert the output to a single argument to git update-index, newlines and all, not what you want.

For instance, I did this in a test repo which is kind of like what you need:
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --verbose --force-remove --remove -- $(git ls-files -- p4-*)' -- --branches

(It blows away all "p4-*" files). If you have filenames with spaces, there may be trouble.

Comment: i have space inside file names. I am fetching them to the update-index command in a loop but it is not recognizing the file now,
FILE="some file.c"
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --verbose --remove "$FILE"' HEAD. It is working fine as long as i give the exact file name instead of the substitution var.

Comment: Better to use `--index-filter 'git ls-files -z \*.c | git update-index --remove -z --stdin'`. This uses null-terminated strings so it can handle file names that include newlines, spaces, and other grotesque characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
# for i in pattern; do git-update-index --remove $i; done
```

Wouldn’t something like that serve your purpose? (I have never worked with git-update-index, though.)